# Rails How to fix Missing mobile template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to update the user information when on mobile but rails log show:

someone know why this happen on mobile mode?

> Missing template users/update, application/update with
>   {:locale=>[:"en"], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, 
>   :coffee]}. Searched in:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @states = State.all
        @cities = City.where('state_id = ?', State.first.id)
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          redirect_to(action: :edit, id: @user, only_path: true, format: :html)
          flash[:notice] = 'updated'

        else
          render :edit
        end
      end
      format.json do
        @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        render nothing: true
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `format.html do` and `format.json do` but you don't have a `format.mobile do` block.

Since the html and json blocks aren't executed, the code falls through and the default for any action is to render the format with the name of the action, so you're in the action `update` therefore rails by default looks for a view `update.html.erb` or `update.html.haml`

Comment: @SteveTurczynyes thank you and i had to do that because of the dropzone js.

so, is just to add a mobile and tablet block!